# error creating new rails project on aptana in windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

i got the following error creating a new rails project on aptana 3.0.4 with rubyinstaller

sh: /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails: C:/Projects/railsinstaller/Stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. I followed the instructions of Aptana support and executed `$ gem install rails` in the Aptana CLI. I was then able to create a new Rails project.

Comment: Hi, that's work, i just could not found this instructions on aptana support, could you paste the link? thank you

Comment: I couldn't find that in their documentation. They emailed that instruction to me after I posted on their support board.