# Rubygems: can't install rails (not in gzip format)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, aptana

I want to install rails to use it with aptana studio 3. After hiting `gem install rails` following error is being thrown:

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Zlib::GzipFile::Error)
    not in gzip format
```

I installed ruby 1.9.2 and and rubygems 1.8.9 seperately (after that I read about ruby 1.9.1+ including gem support already).

My `gem source` is: `http://rubygems.org/`

I have searched for solutions for quite some time. But can't find the issue.

Your help is appreciated :-)

---

EDIT1:

All right. After using the RailsInstaller I can find Rails in my gem-folder. When I try to open a project in Aptana I get the following Error:

```
sh.exe":C:/Projects/railsinstaller/Stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

found simialar issue [here](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/discussions/problems/3263-cant-create-a-new-rails-project) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7493627/error-creating-new-rails-project-on-aptana-in-windows). but didn't help in my case.

---

EDIT2:

I started a new topic since I solved this issue indirectly and a new one occured. To follow my further steps go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675143/cant-open-new-projects-in-aptana-studio-3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution but not a direct one:

http://railsinstaller.org/ <-- here you can find an install-package that istalls all you need...

Answer (score 0):

I used RailsInstaller for Windows but I still had that Aptana error, which I solved by simply calling:

```
$ gem update
```

than, on my project

```
$ bundle update
```

My error was:

```
sh: /c/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.2/bin/rails: C:/Projects/railsinstaller/Stage/Ruby1.9.2/bin/ruby.exe: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

gem update will work. This is because most of the bat files in bin directory refers to wrong railsInstaller path.