# Can't open new projects in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, aptana

I tried the operations as you can see at the image below. Can you please help me to set up ruby/rails, so I can learn that popular technology.

[image]

[*enlarge image*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhyBJ.jpg)

EDIT: There must be an error in my settings with ruby/rails so aptana can't access rails. I have used railsinstaller for windows. rails folder exists under gems folder, so rails should be installed.

EDIT2: It may be proxy settings!?

Comment: I would start here: ruby.railstutorial.org/book. The first chapter gets you up and running on all three platforms.

Comment: I can't see how this addresses my issue. I have already installed ruby/rubygems/rails and can not start a new project using aptana studio. Just linking a general documentation is not very helpful -.-

Comment: You asked for help on setting up ruby and rails. The tutorial has detailed instructions on doing just that.

Comment: I already did that and an error occured like you can see at the image!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are behind a proxy try

**export HTTP_PROXY=http://yourproxy:port** or **export HTTP_PROXY=username:password@yourproxy:port** before trying to install the gem.

Comment: It was the proxy, but I used instructions from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4418/how-do-i-update-ruby-gems-from-behind-a-proxy-isa-ntlm